# the position of checkboxes and radiobuttons changes after using flatten options with iText or disappear

Tags: itext

After using the flatten option in iText checkboxes and radiobuttons change their position or disappear. I'm using iText 2.1.5 but it also happens when using 5.5.8.

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Comment: Show us an example or it never happened! (We have examples where the check boxes and radio buttons don't change position and don't disappear; you have to prove that there are examples that show this behavior if you want help.)

Comment: "Pictures" aren't sufficient. We need to see the PDF; we also need to see your code. Help us help you.

Comment: Thanks for your Feedback!

Comment: https://downloads.compeople.eu/public/dvag_tmp/20151119_Fragebogen%20Bundeswehr,%20Polizei_01_Original.pdf

Comment: https://downloads.compeople.eu/public/dvag_tmp/20151119_Fragebogen%20Bundeswehr,%20Polizei_01.pdf_KOPIE.PDF

Comment: Hope these files are sufficent!

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, but I'd prefer not to help you because you're doing something you shouldn't do. The form you shared is a *signed* document. By flattening that document, you throw away the signature. You should never do that. Why do you need to flatten the document? There's a second signature field in the document. If you add a signature to that field, you can lock the fields so that they can't be changed without breaking the signature. That's how you should proceed. I don't understand why you'd want to flatten that form.

Comment: There's yet another reason why I can't help. Your form is weird. For instance: you have a field named `Art_Risiko_Kampfschwimmer`. This field is a check box. A checkbox can have an `on` value and an `off` value. Your checkbox has an `off` value `/Off` and two `on` values `/Yes` and `/Objekt54`. The bounding boxes of these appearances look strange. Further inspection would be needed to find out if the PDF is a well-formed document. (At first sight, I'd say: I don't think so.)